# how to get multiple input values with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a tag plugin which creates hidden input value as the user enter desired name in the input

for e.g

If i enter hello then plugin will create this hidden input

```
<input id="nameinput" name="tag[27]" value="63" data-tag-id="63" type="hidden">
```

& if i enter hello1

```
<input id="nameinput" name="tag[61]" value="22" data-tag-id="22" type="hidden">
```

now i want to get their value only and want to submit through jquery ajax
by comma separated like this-> 63, 22 as the user can enter maximum 8 tags

i tried using 
`$("#nameinput").val();` but it didn't work

Comment: This is invalid markup. You cannot have 2 elements with the same id. Your plugin is broken.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is there any other way to get these input values?

Comment: Provide the plugin name, so we can get more info

Comment: @IvanRodriguezTorres http://demonstration.easy-development.com/jquery-mt-select/ It's mt select & actually plugin didn't add the id i myself added the id in input

Comment: So use a class better than id, since id must be unique

Comment: @IvanRodriguezTorres ok i have removed the id tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select them by custom attribute this way:

```
var tags = []
$('[data-tag-id]').each(function () {
    tags.push($(this).val())
})
alert(tags.join(','))}
```

But it's bad to have multiple elements with same id.